# How to change image source of image component in c# unity?

Tags: c#, image, unity-game-engine, sprite

I am trying to programmatically change the source image of my image component.

I have a code that I think does it but when I run my unity file, it doesn't show up. I am puzzled as to why, anyone can help?

'''

```
GameObject newobj = new GameObject("newobj");
RectTransform rectTransform = newobj.AddComponent<RectTransform>();
Canvas newobjCanvas = objToSpawn.GetComponent<Canvas>();
newobj.transform.SetParent(newobjCanvas.transform);
image = newobj .AddComponent<Image>();
Sprite FULLHP = Resources.Load<Sprite>("LineSeriesPointTriangle.png");      //loads a sprite

newobj.GetComponent<Image>().sprite = FULLHP;
```

'''

Comment: Is this the correct path?  "Resources/LineSeriesPointTriangle.png"  Is the texture type set to sprite in the import settings?

Comment: hi! The path is really long. I am using a plugin called Graph maker it is it under textures. do I include the path of my unity project folder or do I just shorten it to "Textures/LineSeriesPointTraingle.png". Also the texture type is set to sprite in the import setting!

Comment: The sprite needs to be contained within a `Resources` folder, somewhere in the project.  You can exclude everything up to Resources in the path. ie. `Assets/UI/Resources/Button.png` would just be `Button.png` [Resources.Load](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Resources.Load.html)

Comment: yes, i just now fixed it! thank you so much!!

Comment: this line newobj.transform.SetParent(newobjCanvas.transform); could just be newobj.transform.SetParent(objToSpawn.transform); if you are not doing anything with newobjCanvas object later on

Comment: I do have another question, I am trying to change the x,y,z position of my newobj. I am uing ' Node7object.transform.position = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);' but nothing is changing. Do you know why this might happen?